# Failed to resolve com.androidAffected Modules and com.loopjAffected Modules in android

Tags: android, build.gradle, aar

Failed to resolve com.androidAffected Modules and com.loopjAffected Modules in android.
I have checked with different links but I am confused.

Below is my App build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXX.XXXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:androidasync http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation project(':merchantsdk')


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MerchantSDK is the aar file which is imported into this project and then I build giving below exceptions
Failed to resolve com.androidAffected Modules and 
Failed to resolve com.loopjAffected Modules

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an AAR file you can keep it "lib" folder. You can add dependancy for this AAR in build.gradle as follows: -

```
implementation "packagename of aar:aar filename:@aar"
```

Replace package name and filename of AAR.

In build.gradle file of main project add this: -

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Prashant, Thanks for your response I am confused because I have only ".aar" file.How to get package name of that .aar file ?

Comment: You can keep it in lib folder and add as an module from file menu also.

Comment: Any reference link would be helpful Prashant.

Comment: https://medium.com/@notestomyself/how-to-include-external-aar-file-using-gradle-6604b378e808

Comment: Prashant I have checked with above link 2 ways giving same exception

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct sdk? This might be the issue with the SDK itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201714/discussion-between-prashant-sable-and-naveen).